# EventListener Not Working To Receive new message using Larasocket Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am   work on send and Receive Message to different users using Larasocket In Laravel Livewire.
sending Message and Receving Message Working In DIfferent Users But I added Listener to Listen a New Message
But It Is Not Working. I Need your help

Chat.php(Livewire component)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Message;
use Auth;
use App\Events\MessageSentEvent;

class Chat extends Component
{
    public $messages = [];
    public $text;
    public $users;
    public $selectedUser;
    public $newMessage = false;
    public $userWithNewMessage = [];
    
    protected $listeners = [
        'echo-private:chat,MessageSentEvent' => 'receivedMessage',
        'showMessages' => 'showMessages',
    ];

    public function showMessages($user)
    {
        $this->selectedUser = $user;
        $this->messages = Message::messageList($user['id'])->get()->toArray();
        $this->newMessage = false;
        Message::readMessages($user['id'], \auth()->id());
        foreach($this->userWithNewMessage as $key => $value){
            if($value == $user['id']){
                unset($this->userWithNewMessage[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function receivedMessage($data)
    {
        $message = $data['message'];
       
        if($message['receiver_id'] == \auth()->id()){
            if($this->selectedUser and $this->selectedUser['id'] == $message['sender_id']){
                $this->messages[] = $message;
            }else{
                $this->newMessage = true;
                if(Message::query()->where('receiver_id',auth()->id())->where('sender_id',$message['sender_id'])->where('is_read',false)->count())
                {
                    $this->userWithNewMessage[] = $message['sender_id'];
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $message = $user->sendMessages()->create(['receiver_id'=> $this->selectedUser['id'], 'message'=>$this->text]);
        //send Event to Listener
        broadcast(new MessageSentEvent($message))->toOthers();
        $this->messages[] = $message->toArray();
        $this->text = null;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->users = User::where('id','<>',auth()->id())->get();
        return view('livewire.chat',['messages'=> $this->messages]);
    }
}
```

Chat.blade.php (Livewire Blade)

```
    <div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <h3 class="card-header">{{ __('USERS') }}</h3>
            <hr />
            @if($newMessage)
                <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                    new Message Arrived
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="col-12 row">
                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                            <li wire:click="$emit('showMessages',{{$user}})" 
                                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center {{(optional($selectedUser)['id']) == $user->id ? 'active' : ''}}">{{$user->name}}
                                @if(in_array($user['id'], $userWithNewMessage))
                                    <script !src="">
                                        var title= "new Message";
                                        var body = "new Message From {{$user->name}}";
                                        var notification = new Notification(title, {body});
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">new</span>
                                @endif  
                            </li>
                        @endforeach

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-8">
                    @if($selectedUser)
                        <section class = "">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                                        <div class="card" id="card1" style="">
                                            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3" style="font-size:large;">
                                                <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                                                <p class="mb-0 fw-bold">{{$selectedUser['name']}}</p>
                                                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="message-body" style="height:500px;overflow: auto;flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                                                    @foreach($messages as $message)
                                                        @if($message['receiver_id'] == auth()->id())

                                                            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
                                                                
                                                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-8.webp" alt="avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center mr-2 z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                        
                                                                <div class="p-3 ms-3" style="border-radius:15px;background-color:rgba(57,192,237,.2);height:fit-content;">
                                                                    <p class="small mb-0">{{$message['message']}}</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div> 
                                                        @else
                                                            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4">
                                                                <div class="p-3 me-3 border" style="border-radius:15px;background-color:#fbfbfb;height:fit-content;">
                                                                <p class="small mb-0">{{$message['message']}}</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-4.webp" alt="avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center mr-2 z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                                                                                                </div>
                                                        @endif
                                                    @endforeach
                                                    </div>
                                                <div class=" row form-outline">
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="textAreaExample" wire:model.debounce.100ms="text" placeholder="Type your Message...">
                                                    <button wire:click="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"> send</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    @endif  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

MessageSentEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\Message;

class MessageSentEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }
    
}
```

Message.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Message extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'message',
        'sender_id',
        'receiver_id',
    ];


    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'sender_id');
    }

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'receiver_id');
    }

    public static function readMessages($senderId, ?int $receiverId)
    {
        Message::query()->where('sender_id', $senderId)->where('receiver_id', $receiverId )->update(['is_read'=>true]);
    }

    public function scopeMessageList($query, $selectedUser)
    {
        return $query->where(function(Builder $query) use($selectedUser){
            $query->where('sender_id',auth()->id())
                ->where('receiver_id',$selectedUser); 
        })->orWhere(function(Builder $query) use($selectedUser){
            $query->where('sender_id',$selectedUser)
                ->where('receiver_id',auth()->id());
        }); 
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Models\Message;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendMessages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class,'sender_id');
    }

    public function receievedMessage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class,'receiver_id');
    }
}
```

As I Review My Code and Check So I think Issue Is When User Send a Message '**echo-private:chat,MessageSentEvent' => 'receivedMessage**  Listener Is Not Working

I Need your guidence

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).